# Umbraco 7.1.8 - using Content Type Picker type as Macro parameter

Tags: asp.net-mvc, razor, umbraco, umbraco7

So I'm attempting to utilize the Content Type Picker as a parameter for a macro. When adding the macro to a page, I select the content type with alias "myType".

How do I retrieve the alias of the document type in the partial view of the macro?

Currently, I am using:

```
var type = Model.MacroParameters["myType"];
```

which gives the ID of the document type. Can I retrieve the alias of the document type using the ID?

When using:

```
@Umbraco.Content(type)
```

It returns an empty Content object.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have found a solution that retrieves the document type alias using the content type picker data type:

```
//get current content type service
var myContentTypeService = ApplicationContext.Current.Services.ContentTypeService;

//get ID of selected content type
int typeID = Convert.ToInt32(Model.MacroParameters["myType"].ToString());

//get content type object using ID
IContentType myContentType = myContentTypeService.GetContentType(typeID);

//retrieve alias
String alias = myContentType.Alias;
```

Answer (score -1):

Your method uses the content service, which hits the database, which you don't want on the front end! In your partial, use the following instead:

```
//get content
var page = Umbraco.TypedContent(Convert.ToInt32(Model.Macroparameters["myType"]));
//get Doctype Alias
var alias = page.DocumentTypeAlias
```

As a general rule, you should avoid using the content service for front end display, and use the TypedContent method of the Umbraco helper instead! Hope that helps :)

Comment: I have previously tried that code, but it returns empty objects for both `page` and `alias` - when used with the Content Picker data type, it works as required, but not with the Content _Type_ Picker data type.

Comment: Sorry, I misunderstood the question there, in that case, yes, you will have to use the Content Service. A more efficient way if you just need the alias might be to create your own macro parameter type that stores the alias instead of the ID, negating the need to hit the content service.